# Deleted Answers Edited Post-Mortem Still Move Question Activity

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, deleted-questions, activity

I noticed an issue recently when cleaning up a deleted answer in a question:

#### The activity on the question updated, moving it to the highest position on the "Active Questions" tab.

After I noticed this the first time, I tested it again. It definitely popped up once more with the activity label `modified by VoteToClose 4 secs ago` (see images below).

It goes without saying that this is a problem that should probably be addressed, as question askers can silently move their questions to the top of the activity page and users editing their answers after they're removed may cause problems.

[image: before]

[image: after]

These screenshots were taken in the space of five seconds.

Comment: Wait what? I thought you couldn't edit your own answers when they were deleted? Or is that questions? Heck, I don't know... -_-

Answer (score 9):

That's not a bug.  An edit to a deleted post stands a good chance of being an attempt to improve it.  (Otherwise, why bother?)  Therefore, people who can see deleted posts should know about it so they can decide whether to now cast undelete votes.  Otherwise, the only option is for those users to flag their edited posts and ask a moderator to handle it.  There are a lot more 10k users than moderators, so since 10k users *can* handle it (unless it was deleted by a moderator), why not let them have first crack at it?

I don't understand the concern about bumping.  Anybody can bump his posts now, and editing leaves an attribution trail.  If somebody is using edits to deleted answers to bump his questions, then either he's running a sock or it'll be obvious who did it.